# Flutter setState(() is not updating my Text Value

Tags: flutter

(Flutter)

I am trying to update a text value when I push a button using setState(() but it is not being updated.

I can see when I use print(test) within the button action it prints the correct result.

Does anyone know why this would be happening? Thank you!

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    var test = "hello";
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(test),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(58, 133, 191, 1),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(children: [
            Text(test),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
              color: Colors.red,
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  test = "notworking:(";

                });
              },
            ),
          ]),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `setState` recalls `build`. Since `test` was declared locally in the `build` method, it was reset to `"hello"` each time you called `setState`. State variables are meant to be stored in the state, not in `build`, so move `test` out of `build`.

```dart
var test = "hello";

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(test),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(58, 133, 191, 1),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(children: [
            Text(test),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
              color: Colors.red,
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  test = "notworking:(";

                });
              },
            ),
          ]),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it member variable of class then this issue is resolve.

```
      var test = "hello";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(test),
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(58, 133, 191, 1),
        ),
        body: Column(
            children: [
            Row(children: [
            Text(test),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
          color: Colors.red,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              test = "notworking:(";

            });
          },
        ),
        ]),]
    ));
```